# Get Next Row in a mysqli_fetch_array While Loop Populating HTML Form with Database Data

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP and Mysql programming and I would like to know if I can access another database row when showing data in a form.

Here is the code:

```
$mysql_host     = "";
$mysql_database = "";
$mysql_user     = "";
$mysql_password = "";

$con = mysqli_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);

$result  = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Elev WHERE Clasa = '" . $_SESSION['clasa'] . "' ORDER BY Nume ASC ");
$result2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM M_Profesori WHERE ID = '" . $_SESSION['ID_p'] . "' ");

while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<select>
                <option value='" . $row2["Materia"] . "'>" . $row2["Materia"] . "</option>
                <option value='" . $row2["Materia"] . "'>" . $row2["Materia"] . "</option>
             </select>";
    }
}
```

In the second option (`<option value='" . $row2[Materia] . "'>" . $row2[Materia] . "/option>`) I would like to access the next database row, not this one. Is this possible?

Comment: I'd say, this is very likely possible, however, what would you do on the last row? It wouldn't have a next row then.

Comment: If you're new to MySQL, checkout PDO and start using it. The safest way to query your database http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood, you can try this:

```
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
foreach($row2 as $key => $value) {
   ...
   <option value='" . $row2[$key+1][Materia] . "'>" . $value . "</option>
   ...
}
```

try this...

In adicional, look this:
You can use a template to build better codification. (site in portuguese)
http://raelcunha.com/template.php

http://raelcunha.com/packages/extra/template/pt-br/api/index.php